# Ejabberd wrong timestamp in delayed messages

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

i am using xmpp/ejabberd for chatting, it works properly if the two users are online, but when someone is offline he gets the delayed messages but with wrong timestamp. the time is greater than server's time by about 7 mins

Offline Storage

Comment: Does it happens all the time ? It is possible that the timestamp is only added when connection loss from that user is detected.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond it happens just when one of the users was offline and has a delayed message so he get it with wrong stamp

Comment: created_at column in spool table is correct but when a delayed message stored in it the stamp attribute is greater than server's time by 7 mins.
Please find the xml example below:

delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='***' stamp='2015-09-18T10:55:41Z'
offline Storage
delay
xmlns='jabber:x:delay' stamp='20150918T10:55:41'
message